# Spring Data JPQL How to create a query with dynamic where clause?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm creating custom JPQL queries to fetch some data.
I have certain cases where I would like to add a where clause depending on if the parameter value is non null.

For example equivalent sql query:

```
//If parameter status is not null.
SELECT sum(A.sal) FROM TABLE A WHERE A.STATUS = 'X' GROUP BY A.CURRENCY;

//else
SELECT sum(A.sal) FROM TABLE A GROUP BY A.CURRENCY;
```

Can someone help me with it.

Comment: Take a look at the querydsl support or maybe specifications.

Comment: Is this JPQL in your examples? It looks more like a plain SQL query (although this `table` keyword seems wrong to me. If this nullability of the parameter is the only if-else case then you can wrap it up in a single query without the need of doing something "dynamic"

Comment: For simplicity I have specified just two, generally it'll be more, also yes these are SQL forms, actually I am using constructor to map result set into a non entity pojo.

Answer (score 0):

The two queries:

```
//If parameter status is not null.
SELECT sum(A.sal) FROM TABLE A WHERE A.STATUS = 'X' GROUP BY A.CURRENCY;

//else
SELECT sum(A.sal) FROM TABLE A GROUP BY A.CURRENCY;
```

can be compacted to one.

First lets declare a named parameter `statusParam`. This param can take any value (like `'X'` or `null` from above). So the two queries above can be re-written to:

```
SELECT sum(A.sal) FROM A WHERE (A.STATUS = :statusParam OR :statusParam is null ) GROUP BY A.CURRENCY;
```

Answer (score 0):

Come on, JPQL is just normal String :)
You want something like this?

```
private String generateHql(String status) {
String jpql = "SELECT sum(A.sal) FROM TABLE A ";
if (null != status) {
 jpql += "WHERE A.STATUS = " +status ;
}
jpql += " GROUP BY A.CURRENCY "
return jpql;
}
```